# "Não é que ela sabia de tudo?" ou "Não é que ela sabia de tudo!" Qual a pontuação correta?

Tags: pontuação

A mim soa como uma exclamação, mas não tenho certeza se é uma pergunta retórica.
Qual o tipo de ponto a ser usado?  Ponto de interrogação?  Ponto de exclamação?

Vejamos no exemplo abaixo:

- Olha só!  **Não é que ela sabia de tudo?/!**  Enganou-nos perfeitamente.

A intonação que imagino é a de uma pergunta.  Mas trata-se de uma exclamação.

Comment: tem netflix? tem uma série chamada Explicando... e tem um episódio sobre o ponto de exclamação. Sugiro ver o episódio. Acho que não há resposta certa para a tua pergunta, depende do que quer dar enfase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pontuação correta do ponto de vista gramatical é a usando o ponto de interrogação(?), sendo que a pergunta retórica é reconhecida analisando o contexto em que é feita e o significado das palavras usadas.

Comment: O contexto é aquele citado no OP

Comment: Sim, a pergunta é retórica.